# Workable links through Nodemailer from my GitHub codespace? The email is sent but when clicking the link, the page comes up blank

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nodemailer, appjs

Using GitHub and need to send users to an html page but when users click on link, no content is shown.
[This is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afr5c.png)

The link is -> My GitHub link + hostName + ":8080/page.html"
The hostName is : var hostName = require('os').hostname();

Any idea why this doesn't work?

Comment: is the host publicly visible on the *internet*?

Comment: @Bravo Yes, I set it to public and still the page shows up blank

Comment: *"I set it to public"* sounds like you don't know what I mean - you know, DNS and all that

Comment: @Bravo I'm not sure if this is what you mean but I did try port listen and it didn't work.

Comment: no idea what you're talking about in that comment ... you are using a link to a server ... `My GitHub link + hostName + ":8080/page.html` - now, I have NO idea if that results in a **valid** url - since I have no idea what "My Github link" is, nor "hostName" ... seems an odd thing to concatenate together though ... and there's no evidence that there's even a valid "protocol" portion for that URL (i.e. `http://` or `https://`) - YOU can see what the URL result is, we can't

Comment: @Bravo Yes my bad. So the link constant goes something like this:
 const link = "https://username-code50-80305592-examplecode.github.dev/"+hostName+":3000/page.html";

I know what I did definitely wasn't the right way to make the host public but I tried app.listen(3000). And on Github itself, the option to either keep the server private or public didn't make a difference. Is there any other way to make the host public on the server?

Comment: `https://username-code50-80305592-pjgqg5wrg29p79.github.dev/%22+hostName+%22:3000/page.html` doesn't look like a valid URL .... `https://username-code50-80305592-pjgqg5wrg29p79.github.dev/page.html` does

Comment: @Bravo I used that originally and had the same problem.

Comment: did you - well, not sure what you did wrong